# HTML to PDF - Get footer only on last page only of the pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf, mpdf

I am printing `HTML` output from `summernote` (WYSIWYG editor) to a pdf.

I want footer to be shown only on bottom of the last page.

But that footer should not take any space on other pages.

I mean if there are 10 lines of space on each page and there is 25 lines of content then first 2 pages should have 10 lines of text each and the last page should have 5 lines of text followed by 3 blank lines and the footer in the last 2 lines.

How should I configure mdpf or dompdf to get this output?

I have gone through multiple people asking the same question but no one has received a working solution.